# Failed to resolve: de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

Tried adding both maven repositories but can't seem to get this to resolve.
Couldn't find any info on stackoverflow and was wondering what is the standard way to resolve dependencies in Gradle

Root build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
//        maven { url "https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/de.hdodenhof/circleimageview" }
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
```

Module build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
//    compile files('libs/CircleImageView-master/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.jar')
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
}
```

Failed to resolve: de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0

Answer (score 2):

I can download that dependency as written in the question. For reference, though, here is my project's build.gradle. I think you need the `allprojects` piece. I've had problems where dependencies wouldn't resolve without that.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        mavenLocal()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        mavenLocal()
    }
}
```

An additional note: If you were to compile the cloned repo, you do it something like this

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile project(":CircleImageView-master:circleimageview")

    ...
}
```

Where the settings.gradle would have

```
include ':app', ':CircleImageView-master:circleimageview'
```

Comment: Just realized the issue was not related to the dependency but something to do with my proxy since I was able to compile the dependencies when I connect to my WiFi hotspot instead of the corporate proxy

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the `compile` dependency to the right Gradle file? Make sure the `compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'` line is in the `dependencies {}` block and that such block is in the `build.gradle` file that is in your module folder, not in the root directory of your project.

If it doesn't help, try running `./gradlew clean --refresh-dependencies` from the command line.

Comment: Yep, the root gradle has the repository and the module gradle has the dependencies. I have updated my main post.
I have used the clean build in Android Studio which I believe is equivalent to the gradlew clean but will try this also as soon as I figure it out.

Comment: No, it's not similar, because `--refresh-dependencies` invalidates Gradle cache and forces downloading all dependencies again.

Comment: Should that be run within Android Studio or outside

Comment: You should run it from the command line in your project's path.

Comment: I just noticed this in the gradle build.   A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugCompile'.
   > Could not resolve de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0.
            > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/de/hdodenhof/circleimageview/2.1.0/circleimageview-2.1.0.pom'.
               > Connection to https://jcenter.bintray.com refused
      > Could not resolve de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0.
         
               > Connection to https://repo1.maven.org refused